# Why does rbind with data.table having more than 254 columns reorders column names

Tags: r

I am not sure of the extent of this side effect. Why is this happening ? What caution does one need to take.

```
dt <- data.table(
    sample = 1
)

i = 1
while(i <= 254) {
    col <- paste("x", i, sep = "_")
    dt[[col]] = i
    i = (i + 1)
}

> combined_dt <- rbind(dt, dt)
> print(head(names(combined_dt))) # Columns get reordered
[1] "sample" "x_5"    "x_6"    "x_1"    "x_2"    "x_3"   
> 
> combined_dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt))
> print(head(names(combined_dt))) # Columns do not get reordered
[1] "sample" "x_1"    "x_2"    "x_3"    "x_4"    "x_5"
```

**R details**

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          4.4
year           2018
month          03
day            15
svn rev        74408
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
nickname       Someone to Lean On

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: the two results are the same on my system.  You should, therefore, indicate the `R` version and platform you're using and include code showing how you know there has been a reordering.

Comment: Added the details... also sorry for posting earlier somewhere else, this limit by stack overflow, where i accidently posted on cross validated, did not allow to migrate here for 90 mins.. i will take care next time

Comment: Like @whuber, I can't reproduce your problem. In my machine `combined_dt` shows the columns nicely ordered.

Comment: are u on the same R version ?

Comment: Could be something to do with this, from `?rbind.data.table`: "use.names: 
If `TRUE` items will be bound by matching column names. By default `FALSE` for `rbindlist` (for backwards compatibility) and `TRUE` for `rbind` (consistency with base)."

Comment: Maybe related to this issue: [rbindlist use.names=TRUE returns random column order when ncol>255](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3373)

Comment: Thanks IceCreamToucan and Henrik.